# Covariant derivative of cofactor of metric tensor

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, differentiation

Can anybody please explain why the covariant and partial derivivative (w.r.t the metric tensor) of cofactor of the metric tensor vanishes?

Comment: Do you mean the covariant derivative *of* the metric tensor? Or  is the metric tensor the differentiation variable? Also, do you mean that both the covariant derivative *and* the partial derivative vanish?

Answer (score 1):

What is the "cofactor of the metric tensor", and what does a "partial derivative with respect to the metric tensor" mean?

The covariant derivative of the metric tensor vanishes because the definition of the Levi-Civita connection says that it is something:

1. takes tensors of rank n as input, and maps to tensors of rank n+1
2. Obeys the Leibniz rule: $\nabla(fg) = f \nabla g + g \nabla f$
3. is equivalent to the differential mapping when acting on a field
4. satisfies $\nabla_{[a}\nabla_{b]}\phi = 0$ for all fields $\phi$
5. satisfies $\nabla_{a}g_{bc} = 0$

So, asking why the covariant derivative of the metric is zero is ultimately a bit screwy -- it does that axiomatically, as part of the requirement that covariant derivatives parallel transport.